# ELF interpreter error - Can't install on my CentOS

Tags: linux, executable, 64bit

I don't know if I'm permitted to ask about zPanel here, but I'll go ahead and try and hope for the best. Stackexchange has helped me a lot in different areas...

I was following the instructions to install zPanel on my freshly installed CentOS 6.4 x64 VPS, but I'm facing this error which wont let me finish step 5 from this guide: http://www.zvps.co.uk/zpanelcp/centos-6

So, this is how I'm doing it:

```
[root@img ~]# ./installer-10-1-0-centos-64.sh.x
-bash: ./installer-10-1-0-centos-64.sh.x: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've read through all online solutions and tried running these commands:
`yum install glibc.i686` and `yum install glibc.i386`
For the first package, it said it was installed. The second one wasn't found in my system.

I've also ran this as the guide instructed:

```
yum install ld-linux.so.2 curl
```

But nothing happened.

What do I do in order to proceed?

Comment: `uname -a` says?

Comment: It says : i686.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run x86-64 software on a i686 platform. This will not work. Get the i686 version instead.